# django get specific data from database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have TbPeopleEntranceRights that is referencing TbUser TbRoom and TbArea. TbArea has multiple TbRooms. I wnat to get TbAreas and TbRooms that are not referenced by TbPeopleEntranceRights having a specific user. So I will get the rooms to the user for rooms for which user does not have permission yet.

I need this when having and user and all entrance rights. All rooms and areas.

```
class TbArea(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    area_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)


class TbRoom(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey(
        TbArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='room_area_id')
    

class TbPeopleEntranceRight(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    area = models.ForeignKey(
        TbArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='room_area_id')
    room = models.ForeignKey(
        TbRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='room_id')
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        TbUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='people_id')
    last_update_time = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)



class TbUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=True, db_column='usname')
    password = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, db_column='psword')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get TbArea objects which are not referenced by TbPeopleEntranceRights(*for the logged in user*)then you can do like this.

```
TbArea.objects.filter(tbpeopleentranceright__isnull=True, tbpeopleentranceright__user=request.user)
```

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'tbpeopleentranceright_set' into field. Choices are: area, area_id, create_time, cstm, cstm_id, extend1, extend2, id, last_update_time, remark, room_name, room_no, room_type_id, room_type_name, room_volume, tbentrancerecord, tbpeopleentranceright`

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field` Area and Room does not have user field

Comment: it returns empty queryset, but I got the idea

Comment: if you filter by `tbpeopleentranceright__isnull=True` does `tbpeopleentranceright__user=request.use` after makes sense?

Comment: `tbpeopleentranceright__user=request.user` this will ensure that the `tbpeopleentranceright` objects are particularly for `request.user` If you do not want the specific user related `tbpeopleentranceright` objects then you can remove this.

Comment: could it be done like this?
` tbpeopleentranceright__user=request.user)` using is not?